# Why are software like Adobe Photoshop, Adobe Premiere, Autocad, 3ds max, maya, and many others not made from Java?

Tags: java

These software are being used in many platforms so why don't they use Java to develop these software? Why do they make different source code for each platform?

Comment: Java is *definitely not* the only way to achieve cross-platform support.

Comment: And the technical problem you need to be solved is... ?

Comment: Yeah, and why not just write it all in `C++`?????

Comment: Performance and hardware support are probably the two main reasons, at least for the software you listed.

Answer (score 4):

Just speculating but there are lots of reasons not to use Java in these cases such as

- These packages predate Java.
- They have specialised high performance libraries which are not suitable for Java.
- They have tight platform integration which Java doesn't do well.
- Vendors prefer the software to be difficult to reverse engineer and locked to only one platform. They make their money from selling license for one user or system at a time.
- You can have one source for multiple platforms, the build has to run once for each target but that is a relatively small price to pay.

IMHO, If they were to migrate any of their software, it might be in the direction of [OpenCL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL) or [OpenCV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCV) which are lower level languages for exploiting GPUs. i.e. They are more likely to use a lower level language than a higher level language.

Disclaimer: I am a fan of Java, but its not the best solution for everything.

Answer (score 0):

They do not like to depend on sun / oracle (not a wonder considering Larrys attitude and greed).  And most of programs in question were there before java

Answer (score 0):

All of those programs were written in C++. Java itself was written in C++. This is because C++ can be optimized to be lightning fast, which is why it is still the top choice.

Comment: You mean, most JVM are written in C++

Comment: Yes, most JVMs are written in C++.